# Como saber se um client está acessando o servidor pela rede local ou internet?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Como identifico se o *client* que está acessando minha aplicação, se ele está dentro da empresa (rede local) ou fora (internet)?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Tem alguns critérios que podem ser usados. Acredito que o mais fácil é pegar o IP e verificar se está na faixa possível da rede interna. Isto pode ser feito com a propriedade [`Request.UserHostAddress`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Web_HttpRequest_UserHostAddress). idealmente isto deve ser colocado no *controller*.

Você só vai ter problemas se o acesso interno for feito através de um *proxy* externo ou o acesso externo seja feito por um *proxy* interno, o que é altamente improvável. O mesmo vale para VPNs. Se isto for algo que pode acontecer, não tem como saber de forma confiável, não ser que você possa estabelecer alguma outra regra que só você sabe o que pode ser. Existem algumas formas para **tentar** identificar *proxies* não anônimos.

Método auxiliar para verificar se é rede interna conforme [RFC 1918](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html) (pode não ser o ideal para você):

```
public bool isIpPrivate (IPAddress ipAddress) {
    var ipAddressParts = ipAddress.ToString().Split(new String[] { "." });
    var ipAddressParsed = new int[] { int.Parse(ipAddressParts[0]),
        int.Parse(ipAddressParts[1]),  int.Parse(ipAddressParts[2]),
        int.Parse(ipAddressParts[3]) };
    return ipAddressParsed [0] == 10 ||
        (ipAddressParsed [0] == 192 && ipAddressParsed [1] == 168) ||
        (ipAddressParsed [0] == 172 && (ipAddressParsed [1] >= 16 &&
        ipAddressParsed [1] <= 31));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/LocalOrRemote.cs).

Dá para melhorar, não gosto de usar o `int.Parse()`.

Obviamente não trata IPv6.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0#System_Web_HttpRequest_UserHostAddress)